# Renaming multiple series on all charts on one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, charts, series

I'm still a vba novice so I apologize in advance for a simple problem.

I have about 500 charts with two series each (one is a clustered column and the other is a line).  For each chart, I'd like to rename both series and loop through all charts on the sheet. Below is the code that I started to piece together so far.

```
    Sub RenameSeries()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Loops through charts
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
        With ChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
            .Name(1) = "Name1"
            .Name(2) = "Name2"
    End With
    Next i

    End Sub
```

I'm running into trouble with the `With ChartObject` line.  I'm not sure how to iteratively select each chart, make those two changes, and move on to the next chart. Thank you in advance for reading and providing your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `SeriesCollection` that needs to be indexed, not `Name`. (Each collection only has one `Name`).

I've tested this, but it is essentially the same as Tim's:

```
Sub RenameSeries()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Loops through charts
    For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
        With ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Name1"
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Name2"
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

If one or more of the charts doesn't have 2 SeriesCollections, and you are happy to ignore (skip) this inconsistency, then you can use:

```
Sub RenameSeries()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Loops through charts
    For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
        With ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Name1"
            If .SeriesCollection.Count > 1 Then
                .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Name2"
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

It is better, of course, to debug the code to discover why you have this unexpected inconsistency - perhaps a rogue chart that is hiding behind another one.

---

A side-note, 500 charts is a lot. I would prefer to use, perhaps, comboboxes to dynamically change the data-source(s) for fewer charts. I appreciate, however, that this requires quite a bit of Excel knowledge.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your suggestion. I'm still running into a run-time error (Invalid Parameter) with the second collection (`.SeriesCollection(2)Name = "Name2"`). Any suggestions with that? (There are indeed 2 series on my chart and I noticed when I ran the Record Macro tool, the `SeriesCollection` came up as `FullSeriesCollection` and the names were rewritten as `"=""Name1"""`).

Comment: You are missing a dot in `.SeriesCollection(2)Name = "Name2"`, although I'm slightly surprised that this would run with it missing. It also will probably fail if one of your charts is different - doesn't have two series. Check the value of i that it halts at.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! That was a typo in the comments--it did have a dot. It halts at the second series.

Comment: FWIW, I should add (if it's helpful) that when I ran a similar bit of test code early on, when I only had one series referenced the code ran through and renamed the first of the `seriescollection`. When I added the second, it didn't run and stopped at the second series. Also, when running the Record Macro tool, I verified the series are named 1 and 2 for each chart. Each chart is essentially a copy of the other; only the ranges/references are different, though that doesn't seem like it should really matter.

Comment: I'll guess that the chart it is looking at (when it fails) is either of a different type or doesn't have two series. Yes, `Invalid Parameter` appears if there isn't a 2nd SeriesCollection. You'll need to press Debug and work out which chart its looking at, or use error handling code to skip the naming attempt.

Comment: Well, currently there are 2 charts and the second is a copy of the first. I've updated references for both sets of series. I used named ranges to populate the charts and those in turn get converted into the actual ranges once I hit enter. When I step into the macro, it runs and stops at that seconds series, and it appears it's stopping before it even acts on the first chart, like maybe it's not compiling? To test something else out, I suspended the second series (with an apostrophe), while in the F8/stepping in/out area, I see that it keeps looping through the `With` function without end.

Comment: Andy, you did it! I think it was the If Then function. I was going to reply and say that after suspending the second series (from the first line of code), the macro compiled, but when I removed the apostrophe, it failed. I guess it needed to check how many series there were first. 500 charts IS a lot, but a colleague wants each chart made so that he can copy and paste them into a word doc much later. I think a dynamic chart or your suggt'd combo boxes sound like a great idea, though, as you said, I have some studying to do. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @Nathan - if you have a large number of charts to create and don't need them "live" then one approach is to use a single chart and copy/paste picture after setting each data set.  Then you have 500 pictures instead of 500 (difficult-to-manage) charts.

Comment: @Tim that's a good suggestion bc they will be static once made. I suppose creating them via Andy's comboboxes suggestion would be best the next time a proj like this comes up. Thx again to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub RenameSeries()
Dim i As Integer

    'Loops through charts
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
        With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.SeriesCollection
            .item(1).Name = "Name1"
            .item(2).Name = "Name2"
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much for your suggestion. I ran into an Invalid Parameter run-time error with the second item. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: Maybe you have charts with <2 series?  You'd need to test the `SeriesCollection.Count` property before trying to set the names.